# MongoDb reads happening from a secondary in RECOVERY state

Tags: mongodb

I have a replica set in which a new secondary node is added. That node status is in "RECOVERING". When I try to execute java driver client with Nearest as ReadPreference, some reads are going to the secondary which is syncing and throwing exception.

Should driver be intelligent enough not to make read requests to secondaries that are in "Recovering" state? or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the driver should not be sending requests to a node in a RECOVERING state. I've created a Jira ticket to track this bug:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-753